# How did ancient Greeks connect transcendence and rational approach to one gender(male)?

Tags: metaphysics, ancient-philosophy, greeks, gender

It seems to me as a modern human difficult to connect logic (may say rational approach), material world and something that stays beyond this reality (may say emotional or religious approach), transcendence in one system.

Furthermore, as i understand rational approach for long time considered to be more manly attribute. And in the same time something like will was manly attribute too.
What am i trying to ask is how so happened in western tradition, that two at least independent if not contradictory attributes could be defined to one being (in this context to male).

Is not it easier to define something to male and other to female? For example, someone is very logical and other has will? Yes, then can be that one gender would be like a pure instrument, like computer. Then, is meaning in compensation of something that is lacking? Then why attributes that were defined by Greeks to some gender?

*yeah i know that i can be delusional or whatever about this theme.*

Comment: Maybe because ancient Greek culture (and not only it) was a "male" one...

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of Chinese yin/yang dualism where they tried to think up contrasting pairs and associate them in one big universal pair. For example, they associated (roughly) light, positive, and male on once side and dark, negative, and female on the other.

Greek thought didn't really work that way. The Greeks did have the pairs hot/cold, dry/moist, but they didn't associated the pairs; rather, they made a matrix out of it: hot and dry is fire, hot and moist is air, cold and dry is earth, cold and moist is water. They didn't try to come up with a single universal pairing where every distinction is on one side or the other.

When it came to male and female the Greeks, like most pre-Christian cultures simply thought of male as the greater, stronger, and female as the lesser, weaker. There was no effort to think of female virtues and advantages.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! 
Did not know about matrix. Gonna read about it

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see how ‘will’ is contradictory of ‘logic’. Even if that was the case, that would imply to account just one view of the reality: the logical one. That is, your statement is a logical point of view. But to claim that ‘if something is contradictory, then it cannot occur’, that risks one step even bigger. In fact, when someones have the hegemony while others play the role of the ‘weak’, then what it is possible is imposed by the first ones, and accepted by the last ones (cf. Melian Dialogue). In this sense, men took advantage of the natural differences with women to impose them what was *necessary* at those times. They built the plot of the story at their own will.

Finally, and specially nowadays, I don't see why some people still associate the masculinity with the will, knowing from Genesis that a woman was the first (or second if you count the snake) responsible of the Original Sin, i. e., beginning the pursue of the knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

Logic in Greek is female. Teleology too, male is "acting upon" and female is "becoming of". In Greek most words have a gender that defines the orientation. Female words are basically a process towards. Greek philosophy is the mixing of goals and processes. Unfortunately translation has striped these connotations from Greek philosophy, in a way that it has become an intellectual tool to furnish spiritual emptiness.

Comment: wow, i think it is something, that should be considered...thanks for answer!